# Extract variable string between given strings in oracle sql

Tags: sql, string, oracle

Can you please help me extract the status of every sequence from below, in Oracle SQL? I need to get 'finished' or 'started' or whatever new status the previous sequence may have in that concatenation, that is a result from a previous query.

I need to search by 'account' and get 'finished' in the first case and null in the second case OR search by 'book' and get 'started' in the first case and 'finished' for the second case.

```
STATUS
==========================================================================
sequence_account;finished;sequence_book;started;sequence_content;finished;
sequence_book;finished;
```

Comment: Fix your data model.  Don't store multiple values in a single string.

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a detailed description of the value that you are expecting to be extracted and the steps that you expect the program to take (in English not code). "Or whatever new status the previous sequence may have" is not helpful. How do you define a sequence? Where are you searching by "account" or by "book"?  What are the "first" and "second" cases? Where do we find a "status"?

Comment: Also, why use concatenation in the previous step and make this step more complicated? Why not just skip the concatenation in the previous step and directly use the unconcatenated values as its going to be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using the pattern `;sequence_<term>;<value>;` then just search for the sub-strings that match:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_query ( status ) AS
SELECT 'sequence_account;finished;sequence_book;started;sequence_content;finished;' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'sequence_book;finished;' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(^|;)sequence_book;(.*?);', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS book,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR( status, '(^|;)sequence_account;(.*?);', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ) AS account
FROM   your_query
```

**Output**:

> ```
> BOOK     | ACCOUNT 
> :------- | :-------
> started  | finished
> finished | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=074b9bdbc7f646b167167a979d193da4)*

However, you state that the input is a query you are generating using concatenation. Why bother with the concatenation and, instead, just filter the unconcatenated values.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I need. The concatenation is a result from DataStage and I need to work with it like this.

Comment: @Criss please accept this answer by clicking on the big, gray tick mark below the number of up-votes.